# How to change the TypeConverter attribute of a property at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, propertygrid

I have a class created for use with the PropertyGrid control in a VB.Net application. One of the properties of the class is:

```
    Private _someProp As String

    <Browsable(True), _
     BindableAttribute(False), _
     DesignOnly(False), _
     DescriptionAttribute("Some Property Description"), _
     TypeConverter(GetType(propList1)), _
     DisplayName("Some Property")> _
    Public Property someProp() As String
        Get
            Return _someProp
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _someProp = Value                
        End Set
    End Property
```

**I want to change the TypeConverter attribute of this property at run-time**. I am currently changing other attributes(e.g. Read-only, Browsable) like this:

```
Dim descriptor As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Me.GetType)("someProp")
Dim attrib_r As ReadOnlyAttribute = descriptor.Attributes(GetType(ReadOnlyAttribute))
Dim isReadOnly As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = attrib_r.GetType.GetField("isReadOnly", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic + Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
isReadOnly.SetValue(attrib_r, True)
```

However, I am not able to apply a similar technique to change the TypeConverter attribute. The typeConv variable is 'Nothing' when I try this:

```
Dim descriptor As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Me.GetType)("someProp")
Dim attrib As TypeConverterAttribute = descriptor.Attributes(GetType(TypeConverterAttribute))
Dim typeConv As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = attrib.GetType.GetField("typeConverter", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic + Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
typeConv.SetValue(attrib, IIf(someCondition, GetType(propList1), GetType(propList2)))
```

ETA: **The TypeConverter in this case is used to display a dropdown in the PropertyGrid, so that users can choose an appropriate value, instead of typing in one. I want to change this list at runtime.**

ETA2: With the generous help of a contributor (who decided to delete the answer for some reason), my current position is that I do get a field in the typeConv variable, but I cannot change it. I get an error "Object of type 'System.RuntimeType' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'" on the typeConv.SetValue statement irrespective of the value I provide - GetType(propeList2) / GetType(propeList2).AssemblyQualifiedName / a random string

```
Dim typeConv As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = attrib.GetType.GetField("typeName", BindingFlags.Instance Or _
                                                       BindingFlags.Public Or _
                                                       BindingFlags.NonPublic Or _
                                                       BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
typeConv.SetValue(attrib, value)
```

Comment: You are probably looking for the [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method, but maybe i've just misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter. I think it is the latter. The TypeConverter in this case is used to display a dropdown in the PropertyGrid, so that users can choose an appropriate value, instead of typing in one. I want to change this list at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you could change the `ConverterTypeName` at runtime is to try to use reflection to access the private string member `typeName` and set this to the `AssemblyQualifiedName` of the `Type`.

This is what the constructor of the `TypeConverterAttribute` does internally.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `typeConv.SetValue(attrib, GetType(propeList2).AssemblyQualifiedName)`, where typeConv is the `typeName` field. But that throws an error. Should I be doing it differently?

Comment: Yes: you have to try to retrieve the typeName itself from the typeConv type (it is private, so you will have to fiddle with the BindingFlags), the call SetValue on the typeName member object.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. (As specified in the second edit of my question,) I did retrieve the `typeName` field into `typeConv` using `Dim typeConv As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = attrib.GetType.GetField("typeName", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)`. I get an error on the SetValue statement. I am not sure if this is the correct way to change the value of the `typeName` field.